# Change a mecanim motion reference for a synced layer via Editor Script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Layer1: 
    4 State machines, in each state machine X states. Each of these machines have states with motion references set; some being blend trees.

Layer2 (Synced with layer1):
    In Unity's editor I can navigate the same navigation tree as mentioned in Layer1. And I can change the references to the animation clips just fine.

Question is, how do I do the equivalent in a script? There is no access to these references it seems; in which case how is the Unity editor storing this?

Screen shot of what I am referring to:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/20686/98498/cEhYZ4owenI8ebJ/Test.png

Answer (score 1):

Backend representation.
This is fairly common inside most of Unity's classes, with a few notable exceptions, Unity's UI for example, the repo is open source if you're curious.

If you've ever seen any of Unity's decompiled code then you'll notice that a lot of methods delegate to the actual method, written in C++, on the backend. This is the same setup for a lot of their variables to.

In the animator controllers case, you can access the animation clips at runtime, as the Animator controller inherits from Runtime Animator controller. You are however, unable to swap in new ones. For this you'd need another controller to swap in instead.

You can swap in animation in the Editor though, note ONLY in the Editor, not when you build and ship. The UnityEditor.Animations namespace gives you the ability to build up animator controllers from code. If you look at the decompiled version of these classes you'll notice that a lot of these properties delegate to the C++ to do the actual animator controller building. Then you can use that build version in code.

There is a potential way to build your own animator controller at runtime. Note though, this is your own version, to the best of my knowledge Unity doesn't let you build animator controllers at runtime. You'll be after the UnityEngine.Experimental.Director namespace. This gives you access to custom playables, which can be used to build up animation chains, or maybe even an animator controller, at runtime. Bare in mind though, this is experimental, and may change in future Unity releases.

So your answer is backend representation. The controllers runtime logic is written in C++ with a builder interface being accessible in the Editor. The backend data is serialised when you hit the save button, with the frontend providing a way to reference the backend from C#. At runtime, you use the Animator to control certain facets of the backend.

Some links:

Animations: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorController.html

Director stuff: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.Director.AnimatorControllerPlayable.html

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Great info JJC, I am building a controller via script; and all layers are fine minus the prone layer. Each gun I have is a separate state machine in the controller. The prone animations of the gun are in the synced layers because it is the same structure one to one just with different clips. It seems that the end result is that I can't with mecanim's failed scripting API, at least not on synced layers. The real problem is that I could have hundreds of guns and setting over 100 clips * 100 animations is thousands and thousands of drag and drop and multitude of manhours in doing this :(

Comment: To clarify, I am trying to set these references at editor time, not necessarily runtime. The controller setup just takes waaaay to long to do by hand and since I know 100% the structure, an editor script seemed like the way to go

Comment: An editor script would certainly be beneficial. Take a peak at the AnimatorControllerLayer API, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorControllerLayer.html, it may have the functions you need. Possibly SetOverrideMotions.